# Connect to a public server using pubsubclient

Tags: arduino, mqtt, nodemcu, subscriber

I am using PubSubClient library to subscribe to a server using a nodemcu. I tested the code using cloudMQTT and MQTTlens and it worked fine. In addition to that, I used MQTTlens to check mqtt connection with my pc. In there, I did not specify username and password (I kept blank) and it worked just fine. When I want to connect for a public server (ex: "tcp://11.111.111.111"), does not connect.

code for nodemcu

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* password =  "****";
const char* mqttServer = "****";
const int mqttPort = 1883;

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to MQTT...");

    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {

      Serial.println("connected");  

    } else {

      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);

    }
  }

  client.publish("topic1", "Hello from ESP8266_tester1");
  client.subscribe("topic1");

}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);

  Serial.print("Message:");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");

}

void loop() {
  client.loop();
}
```

the result from the serial monitor

[image: result]

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ip I have provided. IP does not require "tcp://" part. After removing that, the code worked well.

Answer (score 1):

If you genuinely don't require a username and password then don't use the `connect` function that expects them:

```
...
if (client.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
...
```

I see you are using a fairly generic client id - `ESP8266Client`. Remember that all clients connecting to a broker must have a unique client id. If you depoyed this sketch to two different devices they would not both be able to connect at the same time.

Comment: then what should be the function for connecting without using "client.connect()"?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? There are multiple `client.connect()` functions. Use the one that doesn't require a username/password - exactly as I show in my answer above. https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#connect1

Comment: this helped too, but the real problem was with the ip I provided. Thank you